MFC ListControl functions Slowing everything down
I am developing a C++ MFC-based application that takes positional data over IP, does some stuff, sends it back over IP, then outputs it to the list control.  Every packet is collected, processed and sent out.  After the send, I pass the output function to a separate thread so the app can proceed to loop back for the next packet.  The app processes around 3-4 packets a second, on average.
The problem is that the List Control function calls are slowing everything down and creates lag that can be seen on the receiving computer (it uses a map to track the positional data).  It's noticeable, especially because I added a button that toggles output calls on/off.  When output is on, the lag is up to 60 seconds behind.  When  output is off, there is no lag and the map entity snaps to its actual location.
I isolated the problem to the List Control function calls that create each line of data in the List View field.  I tried deferring the rendering of the text on the list using .SetRedraw(FALSE)/.SetRedraw(TRUE) before and after the calls, respectfully, and I discovered that function calls .InsertItem() & .SetItemText() alone was enough to cause the slowdown. I set .SetRedraw(FALSE) without resetting it back to (TRUE) and the slowdown still occurs even without anything being drawn to the GUI. Passing these calls off to a different thread didn't work, but a colleague supposed that was because those functions access/call to the original MFC GUI thread, which would affect all branches from that thread.
So, is there a way to eliminate the problem or do I need to manage the data differently?  I read about utilizing a Virtual List being a possible solution, so if anyone has insight about that I would love to hear it.
void OutputSend(struct Packet_Data sendData, int packetCount, int port)
{
    int dataSize = sendData.data_size - RM_DATA_OFFSET;
    TCHAR outputPacketCount[20];
    TCHAR outputIndexRM[20];
    TCHAR outputDataSize[20];
    TCHAR outputPlayer[4];
    TCHAR outputIP[20];
    TCHAR outputPort[10];
    TCHAR outputProtocol[20];
    TCHAR outputData[4000 + 1];
    
    //************
    //Process and conversions code here.  This is a negligible part and was eliminated as a possible cause.
    //************

    swprintf(outputData, (dataSize * 2), L"%hs", charHex); //convert
    _stprintf(outputPacketCount, _T("%d"), packetCount);
    _stprintf(outputIndexRM, _T("%d"), sendData.indexRM);
    _stprintf(outputDataSize, _T("%d"), dataSize);
    _stprintf(outputPlayer, _T("%d"), sendData.playerNum);
    _stprintf(outputPort, _T("%d"), port);
    _stprintf(outputProtocol, L"%S", sendData.protocol);
    outputData[dataSize * 2] = '\0'; //NULL end TCHAR array
    
    if (m_checkbox_output.GetCheck())
    {
        m_list_platform.SetRedraw(FALSE);
        m_list_platform.InsertItem(0, outputPacketCount);
        m_list_platform.SetItemText(0, 1, outputIndexRM);
        m_list_platform.SetItemText(0, 2, outputDataSize);
        m_list_platform.SetItemText(0, 3, outputPlayer);
        m_list_platform.SetItemText(0, 5, outputPort);
        m_list_platform.SetItemText(0, 6, outputProtocol);
        m_list_platform.SetItemText(0, 7, outputData);//data
        
        for (int i = 0; i < m_list_platform.GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItemCount(); ++i)
            m_list_platform.SetColumnWidth(i, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER);
        m_list_platform.SetRedraw(TRUE);
    }   
}


First thing I would try is removing the for loop that's resizing the columns.

@001  That's the first thing I thought of, too.  A (very) little better when it's deleted (checked using time stamps), but negligible overall.


Check the contents of outputData[] - charHex must contain a null-terminated ANSI (muilti-byte) string, ie a char array or pointer.
You said you are using a separate thread to add the data to the list, you should do the opposite, ie have the main thread modifying the UI and the worker one doing the communication part.
If you store a lot of data into the list, operations/drawing can be slowed-down, and you should consider using a virtual list control.


@ConstantineGeorgiou The threading was a solution attempt to fix this.  I figured since the output was taking so long I would just push it off so the main could get on with it.  Even without the threading, calling the gui functions cause the slowdown.  I can actually see it happen in real time.  When I toggle m_checkbox_output.GetCheck(), the lag instantly disappears.  I do like your suggestion regarding what-thread-should-be-doing-what , though, as it kinda solves an concern I have regarding a feature add I was just assigned.

@ConstantineGeorgiou  The code that doesn't involve the gui is in the //*********** section. What you suggest regarding arrays is there, I just didn't want that code to muddy the water too much.  Although, I see why you ask considering what I left in.  I verified that segment doesn't affect the speed by eliminating the gui stuff.  Works fast.

All the code works, it just slows when .InsertItem() and .SetItemText() start being involved.  It's only really perceptible because I see our data lag (gui output turned on) and not-lag (gui output turned off) on the client side.  It's just infuriating because the issue seems to lie in the MFC calls that I can't really do anything about.  My next course of action is utilizing a virtual list.

In short: Don't add SubItems. (very slow). Use SetItemData() with a pointer to the new data and let it drawn by OnGetDispInfo().  Perfomance gain > 598% for 10k items in my case (687ms vs 4102ms)

My suggestion about threads in the comments was separating the UI from the data retrieval/processing operations, aka "decoupling". Having the latter being carried out in a background (worker) thread, and the former in the UI thread is a quite common configuration. It allows the UI to remain responsive, even if the background thread is busy, performing long or heavy "blocking" operations. If these were run in the main thread, the UI would become "frozen", ie unresponsive, often being unable to even paint itself correctly. And you also want the data retrieval/processing part to be unaffected (slowed down or blocked) by the UI.
In your case (performing UI updates in the worker thread, albeit it was an attempt to fix things) this is what actually happens: you call InsertItem()/SetItemText() from a worker thread, however the control is owned by the UI thread, therefore the UI thread is involved as well, having to store the data into the control and paint itself; while the UI thread is performing all these the calling thread (worker) will be waiting (blocked), as the calls are blocking (or else "synchronous").
Here is a link to a somewhat similar question: Allow start ONLY one thread
There, I'm suggesting performing the data retrieval/processing operations in a worker thread. The worker thread does not modify the UI directly - not even data/variables defined and maintained in the main thread. Instead it notifies the main thread to update the UI. It uses a custom message for this, sending it to the main thread using the PostMessage() function (ie returning immediately, not waiting for it to be processed) and then continues with its normal background tasks - this is for the "decoupling" of the two threads. Now, if the main thread can't cope, this needs to be addressed - it won't be affecting the data processing operations though, ie no lag on the client side in your case.
As for the relatively "slow" listview control operations, this is not due to MFC's CListCtrl, but rather due to the Win32 (common controls) implementation; MFC just sends messages like LVM_INSERTITEM and LVM_SETITEMTEXT. You can see their implementation in winctrl2.cpp. Now why this is "slow" or not as fast as you may want, this is another matter. You can experiment with the following:

Try adding the item to the bottom of the list, if this is acceptable. One might expect the Win32 implementation to be equally fast, but who knows?
Check the properties of your listview controls, for example if the control is owner-drawn and the drawing implementation is inefficient.
Check if adding items to the control triggers other notifications or affects other controls.
Check the Clip Children style of the parent dialog. Is it set? Try toggling it.

